# Clean a messy column and update table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `dbo.mytbl` in SQL Server database where column `sale_date` is messy.

It contains something like  `None`, empty string, `not available`, `2016`, etc - other than those date-like format `2019-12-05`.

It's currently of datatype `nvarchar(max)`.

I can clean up the column like below. All those not like dates are converted to `NULL`

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN ISDATE(sale_date) = 1 
          THEN CONVERT(DATE, sale_date) 
          ELSE NULL 
    END AS sale_date
FROM dbo.mytbl
```

I want to update the table, clean and modify the `sale_date` column in the database, using `alter table`.

How can I achieve that?

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.mytbl
ALTER COLUMN ????????????;
```

Comment: what do you want to do with `ALTER TABLE`? you don't tell us.

Comment: Create a new column., do the update, drop the original column and rename. You can't do this logic by altering the column datatype

Comment: use try_convert()   it will return a NULL if the conversion fails

Comment: Also, a blanket `(TRY_)CONVERT(DATE, sale_date)` could yield very wrong results. What date, for example, is `N'01/02/03'`?

Comment: The syntax of ALTER COLUMN is documented in SQL Server documentation. I'm not sure why you are asking this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `try_convert()`!

If you are not worried about the non-dates, you can do:

```
update mytbl
    set sale_date = try_convert(date, sale_date);
```

This will set all the non-dates to `NULL`.  Then you can safely do:

```
alter table mytbl alter column sale_date date;
```

Comment: Your solution is perfect for my situation.  A follow-up question,  `sale_date` is already converted to `date` with `try_convert`. Why I need to do the `alter table mytbl alter column sale_date date;`?  @Gordon Linoff

Comment: @zesla It will change the data type of the sale_date column so next time it will not allow to insert the messy data like earlier.

Comment: But does the `try_convert(date, sale_date)` already serve that purpose? @Suraj Kumar

Comment: @zesla It has changed the values only in the database it will again to allow to enter the values like none, something, 02/15, etc. so you will get the same situation after some times. But after running the statement like alter table mytbl alter column sale_date date; will not allow to enter these types of data in the column. Hope you will get it now. Also the wrong data type of the date vales was the root cause of the problem.